# Why can't I call and update the child element using its sibling?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently learning JavaScript and testing out how to call and update the children of an element. I was able to update the middle child and I would now like to update the first child using the middle child, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```js
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
var midp = div.children[1];
var midPText = (midp.innerHTML = "This is the middle child");
var firstp = midp.previousSibling;
var firstPText = firstp.innerHTML = "This is the first child";
```

```html
<div>
  <p style="margin-top:2rem; background-color:#ccff33; padding:2rem; color:black;"></p>
  <p style="margin-top:2rem; background-color:#99cc00; padding:2rem; color:white;"></p>
  <p style="margin-top:2rem; background-color:#394d00; padding:2rem; color:white;"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because in between the `<div>` elements is a [TextNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text). This is being selected by `previousSibling` instead of the `div` you're trying to target.

To do what you require use `previousElementSibling` instead. This will select Elements only, not nodes.

Also, as a side note, don't use inline styling. Put your CSS in an external stylesheet.

```js
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
var midp = div.children[1];
var midPText = (midp.innerHTML = "This is the middle child");
var firstp = midp.previousElementSibling;
var firstPText = firstp.innerHTML = "This is the first child";
```

```css
div>p {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  color: white;
}

div>p:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #ccff33;
  color: black;
}

div>p:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #99cc00;
}

div>p:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #394d00;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: The note toward the top of [the previousSibling documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling) makes very clear what is happening here.

Comment: @Adam yes indeed. Did you mean to post this comment on the OP instead of my answr?

Comment: Sorry, I just refreshed myself on how comments work on here. I did mean to post it here, since it was additional to your post, but I should have tagged the OP, because it was for their benefit. @Liquorice

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `previousSibling`, use `previousElementSibling` instead.

```js
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
var midp = div.children[1];
var midPText = (midp.innerHTML = "This is the middle child");
var firstp = div.children[1].previousElementSibling;
var firstPText = (firstp.innerHTML = "This is the first child");
```

```html
<div>
  <p style="margin-top:2rem; background-color:#ccff33; padding:2rem; color:black;" id = "p1"></p>
  <p style="margin-top:2rem; background-color:#99cc00; padding:2rem; color:white;" id = "p2"></p>
  <p style="margin-top:2rem; background-color:#394d00; padding:2rem; color:white;" id = "p3"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: The note toward the top of [the previousSibling documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling) explains why.

Comment: The above was for @Liquorice.